# How to use WhatsApp to pick pictures from Dropbox on a Samsung device?

Tags: samsung, gallery, dropbox

Recently, my old phone broke and I switched to a new Samsung phone. I noticed that the default file viewer and photo gallery app on my old phone would happily connect to Dropbox, this is not the case with the Samsung Gallery/Photos app. I also found confirmation of this on the Dropbox website https://help.dropbox.com/integrations/samsung-device-app.

However, this does make it annoying to send and use pictures that are backed up on Dropbox using WhatsApp and other apps. I wonder if there is a way to select pictures from Dropbox directly. I.e. some apps that will show up in the following list of apps in WhatsApp and other apps:

[image: gallery apps]

P.S. I do know that it is possible to use Dropbox and send something from Dropbox to WhatsApp. However, I find it inconvenient to have to open another app to be able to send pictures. So I would like to be able to instead use WhatsApp to open pictures from Dropbox directly like I used to do with the default gallery app on my previous phone.

Comment: Could you mention the device model and the Android version of the previous phone and the current Samsung phone?